# Ubuntu automatic Updates

Tags: repository, downloads

I keep receiving that my Ubuntu updates are old and I should manually update. I do that and I get a message that the repositories can not download and I should check my internet connection. My internet is working perfectly with all my other programs and other devices. Can someone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: What are you doing to manually update?  Please provide the exact command (or set of commands).

Comment: Also important: which version of Ubuntu is it? It sounds like you've a version that is no longer supported.

Comment: It is 14.04 and I go to the software updater and open that and try to update that way.